# PHP not receiving correct data from HTML using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

The following function is supposed to send data do a php script. When the php script is run, the index _$POST["sessionID"] is not found.

```
function logout(){
  var logoutRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  logoutRequest.open("POST", "server/logout.php", false);
  logoutRequest.setRequestHeader('Conent-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  logoutRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(logoutRequest.readyState == 4 && logoutRequest.status == 200) {
        sessionID = logoutRequest.responseText;
        console.log(sessionID);
    }
  }
  logoutRequest.send("sessionID=" + login_form.elements["sessionID"].value);
}


  <form name="login_form" method="post" id="login-form" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required></input>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn" id="submit-button"></input>
    <input id="sessionID" type="hidden" value="16"></input>
  </form>
```

Comment: is the post data being sent? You can see the post request in developer tools (F12). That will show you the request, posted data, response...etc.

Comment: ya under request data it says: sessionID=16

Comment: You need to call `logout()` after your HTML has loaded, or in an HTML event Attribute `onclick`. `submitForm` needs to return false inside of it, as well. As when it was created.

Comment: its being called outside of the form:
<button id="logout" onclick="return logout();" class="hidden">Logout</button>

Comment: No, you don't return stuff if you're assigning to an HTML attribute. Just put the called function in there: `onclick='logout()'`. I would not even put JavaScript into HTML, unless I cannot avoid it. Separate JavaScript would be like: `document.getElementById('logout').onclick = logout;` or `var logout = document.getElementById('logout'); logout.onclick = function(eventObjectIsPassedHere){funcWithArgs(eventObjectIsPassed Here/*if you need*/, ar1, arg2);};`

Comment: You're making the logout process too complicated with no advantages whatsoever. The proper way to implement this is to use a CSRF token, or just have a direct link to logout.php. If you're sticking with the POST method, just letting you know, it has the same security as just having a simple logout.php linked.